# Unexpected binding behaviour

Tags: angularjs

I have select list i set default option to be chosen. what happen is for few second it works then it disappear and the blank option in the list is chosen as default.

```
 <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.action" ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options">
              </select>
            </div>
```

i want to set defualt option to be chosen :
so my controller look like this:

```
$scope.item = {};
  $scope.options = [{
    title: 'On entering',
    value: 'enter'
  }, {
    title: 'On exiting',
    value: 'exit'
  }];
  $scope.item.action= $scope.options[0].value;

  $scope.profile = me.getUser();
  $scope.profile.then(
    function(user) {
      $scope.owner = user;
      $scope.item = {};
      $scope.item.data = '';
      $scope.item.published = true;
      $scope.item.action= $scope.action;
      $scope.item.owner = $scope.owner.displayName;
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
```

`me` is a service that fecth the user data.
the reason why am defining `$scope.item = {};` again is because i can't apend the `displayName` to the `$scope.item` out of the scope.
I commented this part of the code and it works well:

```
  $scope.profile = me.getUser();
  $scope.profile.then(
    function(user) {
      $scope.owner = user;
      $scope.item = {};
      $scope.item.data = '';
      $scope.item.published = true;
      $scope.item.action= $scope.action;
      $scope.item.owner = $scope.owner.displayName;
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
```

But now i can't figure out how to build my `item` object to send it in `HTTP` request

Comment: can you create a plunker.. above code seems to be fine

Comment: Are you changing the options by any chance later?

Comment: let me paste the rest of the controller code.

Comment: try adding `track by option.value` in ng-options or set `item.action` as just `$scope.options[0]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15490/ fiddle that works perfectly with your code

Comment: Please guys, could look at the editing.